# How to pull Linkedin Pulse Articles

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I cannot find ANY details about LinkedIn Pulse articles in the API documentation. I was just doing a

`file_get_contents($linkedin_url);`

Recently I realized at some point over the last few months that code stopped working and now just returns

`HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 999`

All the API documentation talks about is user profile details and company page details with absolutely no information about articles.

With or without the api, how can I get LinkedIn article details?

The solution typically provided is to use curl and set the user agent, which I have also tried, and linkedin returns the same errors.

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3"
```

I have tested by using chromium browser through Xming to ensure my IP address is not blocked, and I can access the site - however it requires I login. I find this a little unusual as from my regular PC browser it doesn't require a login.

This leads my to believe my IP is not blacklisted. So the question is now, how can I using the API get linkedin article details as none of the other solutions I have found, talk about using the API for this.

Comment: Try to use Curl instead of file_get_contents.

Comment: Unfortunately there is more to it that this. I know the IP is not specifically blocked as I can run chromium and still access the site, but it asks me to login (I am running chromium over Xming to test). Whats unusual is it asks me to login, yet on my own pc/ip it doesn't require a login to access the articles. Curl returns the same problems leading me to believe I should be using the API. The problem is there is nothing about the API at all for accessing articles.

Comment: can you paste a link to an example article? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dont-walk-someone-elses-path-bruce-bates/

Comment: I made a program in Go to fetch the page. When I do it on my windows PC: perfect. When I run it on my server: Bad. I think the issue is the IP address. Try running your PHP script on your local machine & see if it works.

Comment: you are correct, and searching about this, it seems everyone has this problem all over the internet. The API will work fine from hosting, but not public scraping making an API the only solution, and as the api doesn't seem to work with the articles there is little I can do.

Comment: You could potentially use a socks proxy to scrape.